# Salesforce - Field Validation - RegEx for URL

Tags: salesforce

Currently we have a RegEx for a Field Validation on a text field for URL entry.

```
(field__c,'^(https://)?([A-Za-z0-9]\\.|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9]\\.){1,3}[A-Za-z]{2,6}'))
```

This current RegEx doesn't allow for any Page Path beyond the TLD. I feel like there is a minor change to allow for this, but we're struggling to adjust successfully whilst still passing all testing scenarios.

Any thoughts would be appreciated. This is Salesforce specific.

```
(field__c,'^(https://)?([A-Za-z0-9]\\.|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9]\\.){1,3}[A-Za-z]{2,6}'))
```

Tried; and returns a validation error when a Page Path is included in the URL. We've attempted other RegEx's but they fail in other areas.

Comment: The thing is: URLs have an extensive EBNF grammar. You'll only get imperfect regexes, you might as well go for a simple one and extend it bit by bit to fit your precise needs

Comment: I felt like a ? or * at the end would solve to allow anything beyond the TLD.....

Comment: Did you forget the `$` at the end to make sure you check against the entire string?

Comment: Could you please provide a few sample test cases (both for success and failure cases) as part of the question so we can ensure an answer meets your requirements?